# How to update Application having push notification active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I have an application at app store. I have created an update version of it which has push notification active. 
Now i want to ask does my old app-store provisioning profile will work for my update version of application or should i have to recreate the app store profile. 
If i create a new profile for my app then can i add it as an update of existing application at app store.

Comment: why don't u open that provision profile that u attached and check if APNS is enabled in the same or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does my old app-store provisioning profile will work for my update
>   version of application

If for that provision profile Push-Notifications are already enabled then yes, it will work.

> should i have to recreate the app store profile

If you are not sure then you can recreate provisioning profile.

> If i create a new profile for my app then can i add it as an update of existing application at app store

Yes, you can. The most important point here is that your old and new AppId's should be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can update the provisioning profile on an app that is already in the App Store.